# Can I download software update and apply them on another iMac

Tags: software-update

I have the same iMac twice at two different locations. On one location I have a good internet connection but on the other one I have internet over satellite and it is limited to 3GB / month. I would like to know if there is a way to download software updates at one location and apply them at the other one? (I've already managed to download the mountain lion install package and copy it on an USB stick, but now I'd like to the same for the iPhoto update for example).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. However instead of getting the update through Software Update look for the update web page. e,g, [10.7.4 update for Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1525) and [iPhoto 9.2.3](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1514). I found the latter by google search `site:apple.com iPhoto update`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is already available in Lion, but in Mountain Lion you can access the  **combo software updates** in four steps.

First click on the *Apple icon* in the menubar, and then on *About this Mac*:

[image]

[image]